# Simulated NAT Traversal on Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I have installed virtual box ( with Two virtual Adapters(NAT-type)) - Host (Ubuntu -10.10) - Guest-Opensuse-11.4. My Objective is to simulate all four types of NAT as [defined here](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/TOP/NAT+Traversal+Testing). Simulating the various kinds of NATs can be done using Linux `iptables`. In these examples, eth0 is the private network and eth1 is the public network.

Full-cone:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source <public ip goes here>
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination <private ip goes here>
```

Restricted cone:

```
iptables -t nat POSTROUTING -o eth1 -p tcp -j SNAT --to-source <public ip goes here> 
iptables -t nat POSTROUTING -o eth1  -p udp -j SNAT --to-source <public ip goes here> 
iptables -t nat PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination <private ip goes here> 
iptables -t nat PREROUTING -i eth1 -p udp -j DNAT --to-destination <private ip goes here> 
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -j DROP 
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p udp -m state --state NEW -j DROP
```

Port-restricted cone:

```
 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source <public ip goes here>
```

Symmentric:

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables --flush
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE --random
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

I setup an OpenSuse guest with Two Virtual adapters, eth0 and eth1.

- eth1 with address 10.0.3.15 / eth1:1 as 10.0.3.16
- eth0 with address 10.0.2.15

Then ran the [stund](http://sourceforge.net/projects/stun/) client/server...

Server:

```
eKimchi@linux-6j9k:~/sw/stun/stund> ./server -v -h 10.0.3.15 -a 10.0.3.16
```

Client:

```
eKimchi@linux-6j9k:~/sw/stun/stund> ./client -v 10.0.3.15 -i 10.0.2.15
```

...on all Four Cases It is giving same results :

test I = 1 test II = 1 test III = 1 test I(2) = 1 is nat = 0 mapped IP same = 1 hairpin = 1 preserver port = 1 Primary: Open Return value is 0x000001

**Q-1:** Please let me know If any has ever done, It should behave like NAT as per description but nowhere it working as a NAT.

**Q-2:** How NAT Implemented in Home routers (Usually Port Restricted), but those also pre-configured iptables rules and tuned Linux

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "control" the different types of NAT with the guests running under any kind of hypervisor, then you need to run the guests under the "bridged" networking mode.

Comment: My Overall Objective is NAT Simulation on same guest machine, If I have 3-4 Virtual Adapters in that, then I should be able to configure above NAT rules via iptables. and just on same machine (same Virtual Box Instance), I should be able to run stund client/server (bind it on specific interface) and if I set Port Restricted rules then result (stund client/server) should Port Restricted like that.  / but its not happening !! On packet capture it doesn't capture from eth0 or eth-1 It captures from Pseudo Interfaces !!

Comment: Are the NICs on the guests in bridged mode (e.g. no NAT from the hypervisor)?

Comment: Yes NICs are on Bridge Mode

Comment: Where are you running the packet captures and what is it looking at/for?

Comment: I am running Packet Captures in Guest Machine Ubuntu ( with Two Virtual Adapters - eth0 and eth1) e.g; Configured rule for Port Restricted from above (iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source <public ip goes here>) , But while capturing the packets - I saw - Packets are not picked up from eth0 or eth1 interface, packets are picked up from pseudo-device Interface. While rules are configured based on eth0-eth1 interfaces , [On Packet movement nothing filtered up via iptables]

Comment: Does the pseudo-device have anything to do with the hypervisor or is this something else you installed onto your guests?